# Norm inequality for a random matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, measure-theory, normed-spaces, expected-value

Let $X$ be an $m\times n$ random real matrix with integrable entries. Can I show that

$$\|E[X]\|\leq E[\|X\|]$$

where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the Frobenius norm?

I tried different combinations of Cauchy-Schwarz and Jensen, but did not succeed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't that follows from triangle inequality ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper What do you mean?

Comment: It's Jensen inequality + triangle inequality, it works for any normed vector space.

Comment: @InfiniteLooper Could you write down the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality, $\mathbb E[X_{ij}]^2 \le \mathbb E[X_{ij}^2]$ for all $i,j$, so
$$\begin{align}\Vert \mathbb E[X]\Vert^2 &= \sum_{1\le i,j\le n}\mathbb E[X_{ij}]^2\\
&\le \sum_{1\le i,j\le n}\mathbb E[X_{ij}^2]\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}X_{ij}^2\right]\ \text{ (by linearity)}\\
&=\mathbb E\left[\Vert X\Vert^2\right]\end{align} $$

<s>Applying square root on both sides yields the desired inequality.</s>

---

**Update :** My above attempt does not work, and the result is in fact a consequence of the [measure-theoretic formulation of Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_and_probabilistic_form) which states that
$$\varphi\left(\int_\Omega fd\mu\right) \le \int_\Omega\varphi\circ f\ d\mu $$
For any $\mu$-measurable $f : \Omega \to A$ and convex $\varphi : A \to \mathbb R$. In particular, the desired result follows from applying it to $f\equiv X : \Omega \to \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ and $\varphi \equiv \Vert\cdot\Vert : \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$.

To give a more satisfactory explanation, I write down the proof of the result for the specific $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ case, but the argument is basically the same as the one given in the Wikipedia article :

For $\varphi : \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ convex, there is for every $x\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ a non-empty set of subgradients at $x$. Therefore, for any $x_0\in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$, we can find $a\in\mathbb R$ and $b\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ such that for all $x\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$,
$$ \varphi(x) \ge a + \langle b,x\rangle\tag1$$
$$ \varphi(x_0) = a + \langle b,x_0\rangle\tag2$$
Where $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle $ is the inner product of $\mathcal M_n(\mathbb R)$ i.e. $\langle A,B\rangle =  \mathrm{Tr}(A^TB)$. In particular, if I substitute in $(1)$ $x$ by the random variable $X$ and let $x_0\equiv \mathbb E[X]$, these two equations become
$$ \varphi(X) \ge a + \langle b,X\rangle\tag{1'}$$
$$ \varphi(\mathbb E[X]) = a + \langle b,\mathbb E[X]\rangle\tag{2'}$$
Now, by applying expectation to line $(1')$ we get
$$\begin{align}\mathbb E[\varphi(X)] &\ge a + \mathbb E[\langle b,X\rangle]\\
&=a + \langle b,\mathbb E[X]\rangle \ \text{ (by linearity) }\\
&=\varphi(\mathbb E[X]) \ \text{ (by equation [2']) }\\
&\square\end{align} $$

Comment: In the last step it seems you get $E\left[\Vert X\Vert^2\right]$, not $E\left[\Vert X\Vert\right]^2$.

Comment: Ah, right, let me (try to) fix that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Looks good to me. I came up with another possible way below. Do you think its ok? I will accept your answer.

Comment: No problem. And yeah I think your proof looks good too. Using the standard machinery is a great idea I didn't think of !

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$ denote the underlying probability space.

First suppose $X$ is a simple random matrix, by which I mean that there exists a finite partition $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal F$ of the sample space $\Omega$ and real $m\times n$ nonrandom matrices $X_1,\dots, X_n$ such that

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i 1_{A_i}$$

Then $$\|E[X]\|=\bigg\|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i P[A_i]\bigg\|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n \|X_i \|P[A_i]=E[\|X\|]$$

so the inequality holds in this case.

Now let $X$ be an arbitrary $m\times n$ random matrix. Then there exists a sequence $(X_k)$ of simple $m\times n$ random matrices statisfying

(i)$\|X_1\|\leq\|X_2\|\leq\dots\leq\|X\|$

(ii)$X_k\to X$ pointwise as $k\to \infty$ with respect to the Frobenius norm.

To see this, approximate each component $X^{ij}$ by a sequence of simple functions $(s_k^{ij})$ with $|s_1^{ij}|\leq |s_2^{ij}|\leq\dots\leq |X^{ij}|$ converging pointwise to $X^{ij}$. Then let $X_k^{ij}=s_k^{ij}$. Then $(X_k)$ is a sequence of simple matrices (consider a common refinement of the partitions defining each $s_k^{ij}$), and it satisfies (i) and (ii).

By the dominated convergence theorem and continuity of the Frobenius norm we have

$$\|E[X_n]\|\to\|E[X]\| \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty$$

$$E[\|X_n\|]\to E[\|X\|] \quad \text{as} \quad n\to \infty $$

Since  $\|E[X_n]\| \leq E[\|X_n\|]$ for each $n$ we conclude that $\|E[X]\| \leq E[\|X\|] $.